# Total order on $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{\geq 0}$

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

> Suppose that $ < $ is a total order on $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{\geq 0}$ satisfying:
>
> 1.) $\alpha < \beta \iff \alpha + \gamma < \beta + \gamma$ for all $\alpha ,\beta , \gamma$
>
> 2.) $\vec{0}$ is the smallest element in $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{\geq 0}$ in this order.
>
> Must it follow that $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{\geq 0}$ is well-ordered under this ordering? That is, every non-empty subset has a least element?

Comment: How is $+$ defined here? As componentwise addition of the $n$-tuples?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking of a possible counterexample being $\mathbb{Z}^{2}_{\geq 0}$ with $(a,b) < (c,d)$ if $\begin{cases} \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d} \end{cases}$. But it is not defined for $(0,0)$

Comment: Certainly it would be sufficient to show that $S \cup \{ 0 \}$ has a second smallest element, for every $\emptyset \neq S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^{n}_{\geq 0}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Completely revised.**

Let $\alpha=\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle,\beta=\langle b_1,\ldots,b_n\rangle\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}^n$. If $a_k\le b_k$ for $k\in[n]$, then $\vec 0\le\beta-\alpha$, so $\alpha\le\beta$. Thus, $\alpha>\beta$ implies that $a_k>b_k$ for some $k\in[n]$.

Now suppose that there are $\alpha_k=\langle a_1^{(k)},\ldots,a_n^{(k)}\rangle\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}^n$ for $k\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$ such that $\alpha_k>\alpha_{k+1}$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$. Let $A=\{\alpha_k:k\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}^n\}$, and let $P$ be the set of two-element subsets of $A$. For each $\{\alpha_k,\alpha_\ell\}\in P$ let

$$c:P\to[n]:\{\alpha_k,\alpha_\ell\}\mapsto\min\left\{i\in[n]:a_i^{(\min\{k,\ell\})}>a_i^{(\max\{k,\ell\})}\right\}\;.$$

The [infinite Ramsey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem) ensures that there are an infinite $A_0\subseteq A$ and an $i_0\in[n]$ such that $c(\{\alpha_k,\alpha_\ell\})=i_0$ whenever $\alpha_k$ and $\alpha_\ell$ are distinct elements of $A_0$. But this is impossible, since $\langle a_{i_0}^{(k)}:\alpha_k\in A_0\rangle$ is then a strictly decreasing infinite sequence of non-negative integers. Thus, there is no infinite descending chain in $\langle\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}^n,\le\rangle$, which is therefore a well-order.

Comment: I am not sure how to show it is not a well-order. For $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^{2}_{\geq 0}$, can you define $(x,y) \in S$, such that $x+y = \min\{ a + b : (a,b) \in S \}$. Then isn't $(x,y)$ a minimal element?

Comment: @user100101212: My apologies: I forgot that $\le$ is required to be a **total** order. My example here fails to be a well-order precisely because it’s not a total order. Let me know when you’ve seen this comment, and I’ll delete the answer.

Comment: Yes,  I have seen it.

Comment: @user100101212: It is in fact a well-order, though it takes a little work to prove it.

Comment: This is a trivial comment, but $\{ \alpha_{k} , \alpha_{l} \} \mapsto \min \{ i : a_{i}^{k} > a_{i}^{l} \}$ requires $k < l$ otherwise it is not well defined, right?

Comment: @user100101212: You’re absolutely right; I’ll fix that in a few minutes.